# MySQl: triggering an insertion before updating, if the not existing

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm not really familiar with MySQL. But for performance reasons i want to avoid checking if a row already exists. Currently I've got a table with 2 columns (num, count) and I do something like this:

```
SELECT num FROM numbers WHERE num = 123
```

then if row exists...

```
UPDATE numbers SET count = count + 456 WHERE num = 123
```

else if row not exists...

```
INSERT INTO numbers (num, count) VALUES (123, 456)
```

Is there a possibility to avoid always querying the table. Something like a trigger... In the end, i just want to make an UPDATE, so that insertion is done automatically. thanks in advance

Comment: Have you checked 'Insert ... On duplicate key update'  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use triggers, all you have to do is add UNIQUE constraint to your `num` column and then:

```
INSERT INTO numbers SET num = 123, count = 456 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE count = count + 1;
```

Also, don't use reserved words for column names such as COUNT.

Comment: You mean bulk inserts? I'm not 100% sure, but I'd say it does (I also don't have time to try it now to confirm).

Comment: yes, i've checked it. more info see here http://www.bigdbahead.com/?p=60. thanks help for your!